# Creating JDBC Application

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I have this piece of code:

```
try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?characterEncoding=utf8","root","Icdjoil100");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from t_user");
            while(rs.next())
                //System.out.println(rs.getInt(0)+"  "+rs.getString(1));
            con.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but I have this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkClosed(ResultSet.java:666)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.next(ResultSet.java:7274)
    at Test.main(Test.java:19)
```

Comment: You should use braces `{` and `}` with your `while` statement, for clarity - and take a look at the sample code in [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) regarding result set iteration (and closing statements afterwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you commented out your print statement, your loop is now closing the connection (and all of its dependent resources). Your code, without the commented out line:

```java
while(rs.next())
    con.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like :

```
while(rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(0)+"  "+rs.getString(1));
}
con.close();
```

You are missing {}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually closing connection its better to use benefit of jdk 7 to automatically close resources after try. [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html#xd_co_f=MmEyNDllNGY2OTUwNTliYTY3NTE1ODY5NTY3Mzk3MTY=%7E) for reference for try-with-resources.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


  try (
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?characterEncoding=utf8","root","Icdjoil100");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from t_user")) {
              while(rs.next())
            //System.out.println(rs.getInt(0)+"  "+rs.getString(1));

}
```

Even if you don't want to use benefit of jdk 7, its better to close resolurces in finally block so that if there is any exception, it would still be closed correctly.

```
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt= null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con= DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?characterEncoding=utf8","root","Icdjoil100");
            stmt=con.createStatement();
            rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from t_user");
            while(rs.next())
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(0)+"  "+rs.getString(1));
            
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
       if (rs != null) {
          try {
             rs.close();
           } catch (SQLException e) {  }
         }
      if (ps != null) {
         try {
             ps.close();
         } catch (SQLException e) {  }
      }
      if (conn != null) {
         try {
           conn.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {  }
   }

 }
```